# Google App Engine - multiple apps and multiple domains?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps, multiple-domains

I'm currently wrestling with Google App Engine to build multiple apps (3, for right now) to work as both personal and promotional sites.  I'm having trouble redirecting my custom domains to the default app engine ones, though.

Everything worked fine for the first app, including letting me add the (www) subdomain, since in Google Apps I set it as the "primary domain."  But the documentation seems to indicate that I can't do that for any subsequent apps with the same Apps account.

The only reason I got a Google Apps account was to redirect my custom domains - I don't care about mail or calendar or any of the other included apps.  Is there some way to map custom domains to each of my App Engine apps without spending $50 on a new Apps account for each one?

Thanks tons for any help, this has been really frustrating so hopefully there's a simple solution that I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you add the new domain to the "domains" section in Google Apps as an alias, not as a new domain.  This seems disingenuous, but it's just how GAE/GA is set up.  Then, add your new App Engine app in the "App Engine Apps" section of Google Apps.  From there, you should be able to add the new custom domain name to the new app like you did for the first one.